# how can i change is_active in database using a toggle button in python language

Tags: python, django, database, boolean, toggle

how can i change is_active in database using a toggle button in python language.

```
index.html
<table>
{% if user_detail.user.is_active %}
<td><label class="switch ">
<input type="checkbox" id="{{user_detail.user_id}}" value="{{user_detail.user.is_active}}" checked>
<span class="slider round">
</label>
</td>
{% else %}
<td><label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox" id="status1" value="{{user_detail.user.is_active}}">
<span class="slider round">
</span>
</label>
</td>
{% endif %}
</table>
```

Comment: use forms to post the change and then serve the view for that POST request to change value in db

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.